# Logical indexing and double precision numbers

Tags: matlab, data-structures, double, logical-operators

I am trying to solve a non-linear system of equations using the Newton-Raphson iterative method, and in order to explore the parameter space of my variables, it is useful to store the previous solutions and use them as my first initial guess so that I stay in the basin of attraction.

I currently save my solutions in a structure array that I store in a .mat file, in about this way:

```
load('solutions.mat','sol');
str = struct('a',Param1,'b',Param2,'solution',SolutionVector);
sol=[sol;str];
save('solutions.mat','sol');
```

Now, I do another run, in which I need the above solution for different parameters NewParam1 and NewParam2. If Param1 = NewParam1-deltaParam1, and Param2 = NewParam2 - deltaParam2, then

```
load('solutions.mat','sol');
index = [sol.a]== NewParam1 - deltaParam1 & [sol.b]== NewParam2 - deltaParam2; 
% logical index to find solution from first block
SolutionVector = sol(index).solution;
```

I sometimes get an error message saying that no such solution exists. The problem lies in the double precisions of my parameters, since 2-1 ~= 1 can happen in Matlab, but I can't seem to find an alternative way to achieve the same result. I have tried changing the numerical parameters to strings in the saving process, but then I ran into problems with logical indexing with strings.

Ideally, I would like to avoid multiplying my parameters by a power of 10 to make them integers as this will make the code quite messy to understand due to the number of parameters. Other than that, any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: instead of using `==`, why not keep some small margin. Say 1e-10 (or `eps`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never use `==` when comparing double precision numbers in MATLAB. The reason is, as you state in the the question, that some numbers can't be represented precisely using binary numbers the same way 1/3 can't be written precisely using decimal numbers.

What you should do is something like this:

```
index = abs([sol.a] - (NewParam1 - deltaParam1)) < 1e-10 & ...
        abs([sol.b] - (NewParam2 - deltaParam2)) < 1e-10;
```

I actually recommend not using `eps`, as it's so small that it might actually fail in some situations. You can however use a smaller number than `1e-10` if you need a very high level of accuracy (but how often do we work with numbers less than `1e-10`)?